# EF Linq Select statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need help with a linq statement.

I need to 
`select * from ZipCodeCarrierRoute` table but only retrieve the child objects from `Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments` and `contacts where Contacts.Active = true`.

and help would be appreciated.

[image]

UPDATE: Here is the json response for the solution @Yuliam  offered. It;s still not quite right.

[image]

Comment: Create a model class with all the fields you want, than write a linq statement using navigation properties.

Comment: Not much. I'm not sure how to access the contact in a sub query. I have db.ZipCodeCarrierRoute.Where(x => x == ZipCode) which was the original linq statement. From here I can see Cotact_CarrierCode_Assignment but I don't see the Contact entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to retrieve `ZipCodeCarrierRoute` that includes only active `Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments`.

```
var query = db.ZipCodeCarrierRoute
    .Where(x => x.ZipCode == ZipCode)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        ZipCodeCarrierRoute = x,
        Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments = x.Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments
            .Where(y => y.Contact.Active)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(a => a.ZipCodeCarrierRoute);

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuliam, that's very close. The problem is that I only get one contact back in the collection. For the test item I have 2 assignments associated with contacts so I should get 2 back. Using this statement, if I set the first contact to Inactive then I get the second contact which is still active. When I set the contact back to active then I only get that contact back.

Comment: @Tim, you need to execute the code again after you changed the value in the database, this should include `Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments` where `Contact` is active

Comment: I did, I mis-read the json response. It does return the second contact. Thanks

Comment: Correction both are still showing up. The inactive contact just shows at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61240/discussion-between-yuliam-chandra-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I think on top of my head, I didn't test it on a computer or linqpad

```
var query = 
    from zipCodeCR in db.ZipCodeCarrierRoute.
    where zipCodeCR.Contact_CarrierCodeAssignments.All(contact_codeAssignment => contact_codeAssignment.Contact.Active==true)
    select zipCodeCR;
```

Comment: Not quite. I was going down that path but I was using Any instead of All.   var routes = from a in db.ZipCodeCarrierRoutes
                where a.ZipCode == zipCode && a.Contact_CarrierCode_Assignments.Any(x => x.Contact.Active == true)
                ; gave me the correct construct but not the correct result. Using your suggestion didn't return any assignments or contacts